# different array length in if statement out of bound exception

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, if-statement

I have a long if statement where I check different combinations of possibilities. 
Here is the current code I have:

```
for (let i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
 if (taste[0] == movies[i].genres[0].name ||
     taste[0] == movies[i].genres[1].name ||
     taste[0] == movies[i].genres[2].name ||
     taste[1] == movies[i].genres[0].name || 
     taste[1] == movies[i].genres[1].name ||
     taste[1] == movies[i].genres[2].name ||
     taste[2] == movies[i].genres[0].name ||
     taste[2] == movies[i].genres[1].name ||
     taste[2] == movies[i].genres[2].name
 ) {
     moviesForUser.push(movies[i].original_title);
   }
}
```

My Problem:
Some of the movies hava different amounts of genres. That means that in some cases I run into an out of bound exception. How can I check all the possible combination options under consideration of the array length?

Comment: You have to use nested for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use more dynamic methods to avoid that you hardcode indexes like that:

```
moviesForUser = movies.filter(movie => movie.genres.some(genre => taste.includes(genre.name)))
                      .map(movie => movie.original_title);
```

This replaces your loop entirely.

Answer (score 0):

**more readable version:**

```js
let moviesForUser = [];

for (let i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
    let genreFound = false;
    for (let j = 0; j < movies[i].genres.length; j++) {
        if (taste.includes(movies[i].genres[j].name)) {
            genreFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (genreFound) {
        moviesForUser.push(movies[i].original_title);
    }
}
```

**shorter version:**

```js
let moviesForUser = movies.reduce((result, movie) => {
    if (movie.genres.some(genre => taste.includes(genre.name))) {
        result.push(movie.original_title);
    }
    return result;
}, []);
```